# andFilter not showing every search result jtable java

Tags: java, arraylist, jtable

I have a jtable and i want to filter its contents, its kind of working but it only filters for one row.

Basically i want it to show up each row that is matching the search criteria (e.g. entering first name, last name of two different people will show two different rows) but it either shows one, or none at all

```
public void searchCriteria(){
```

DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel) tblStudentDetails.getModel();

```
    String searchiD = txtId.getText();
    String searchfName = txtFName.getText();
    String searchlName = txtLName.getText();
    String searchGender = txtGender.getText();
    String searchAddress = txtAddress.getText();
    String searchPostCode = txtPostCode.getText();
    String searchCompSci = txtCompSci.getText();
    String searchMaths = txtMaths.getText();
    String searchEnglish = txtEnglish.getText();

      ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(9);
      TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(table);
      tblStudentDetails.setRowSorter(tr);

      filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchiD, 0));
      filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchfName, 1));
      filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchlName, 2));
      filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchGender, 3));
      filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchAddress, 4));
      filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchPostCode, 5));
      filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchCompSci, 6));
      filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchMaths, 7));
      filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchEnglish, 8));
      tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(filters));
```

}

My Program looks like this:

[If typed 1(in ID texbox) and V(in First Name text box) the first two lines should show up)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfhcs.png)
Please let me know what I'm doing wrong! thank you!

Comment: Do you have sample data, including your filters and expected output

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post